# Read two folders in a for loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop

I implemented a bash script or I read two input files.
I want the two folders I read to increment their respective files at the same time.

My example is :

```
for folder1 in $in1/*;
do
for folder2 in $in2/*;
do

file1=`basename "$folder1`

file2=`basename "$folder2"`

done 
done
```

I wanted to know if it was possible to make a for loop to increment at the same time?

I thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to happen if the folders have a different number of files in them?

Comment: Hello, the two files have identical numbers but different names. for example : folder1:(file1:01test, file2: 02test...) and folder2:(file1:01car, file:02car...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to store the filenames in a pair of arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

first=( "$in1"/* )
second=( "$in2"/* )

for i in "${!first[@]}"; do
    first_file=${first[i]}
    second_file=${second[i]}
done
```

`"${!first[@]}"` expands to the list of keys in the first array, so `i` will take the values `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

If your arrays are of unequal length you will have to decide how you want to deal with that. Also, the files in each array will be in alphabetical order.